# Remove trailing white space in python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, character, trailing

Having bit of trouble with a program i made. i am getting it to display a diamond but i have a problem, here is my code:

```
a = input("Enter width: ")
a = int(a)
b = a
for i in range(a):
  i = i + 1
  b = a - i
  text = " " * b + " " + "* " * i
  print(text[:-1])
for i in range(a):
  i = i + 1
  b = a - i
  text = " " * i + " " + "* " * b
  print(text[:-1])
```

Thanks for all the help! this is the answer

Comment: First of all: `i = i + 1` in a `for` loop is pretty strange. Why do you want to change the iteration variable in a loop?

Comment: @gefei i did that because a python loop starts at point 0 and i need it to start at 1.

Comment: your slice in on the print return value. put in on the string.

Comment: Well thanks to all your input. I did what Ashwini said and it works! Thank you!

Comment: @user2655778 You need `range(a-1)`.

Comment: The `range` can also start from 1 -- just use `range(1, stop)`. See the doc http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `print` doesn't return the string, it returns `None`.

```
>>> print(print("foo"))
foo
None
```

Perhaps you wanted to do this:

```
text = " " * i + " " + "* " * b
print (text[:-1])
```

To remove the trailing white-space better use `str.rstrip`:

```
>>> "foo ".rstrip()
'foo'
```

help on `str.rstrip`:

```
>>> print (str.rstrip.__doc__)
S.rstrip([chars]) -> str

Return a copy of the string S with trailing whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your slice like this (not on the print return value):

```
("* "*b)[:-1]
```

or, you can use join:

```
' '.join(['*']*b)
```